# Angular applications, express.js server, sending an email via form on the front-end side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, server

Error sending message:
Object { headers: {…}, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/invia-email", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/send-email: 500 Internal Server Error", error: "Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8 https: //support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials cm42-20020a170906f5aa00b009ff8f199f21sm1832983ejd.19 - gsmtp" } error in console. chatgpt tells me "Less secure login: If you are using a Gmail account, you may need to enable "Less secure login" in your Gmail account. Go to this page and make sure "Less secure app login" is enabled." Do you know a trick?

```
server.js const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;  // Puoi scegliere la porta che preferisci

// Middleware per consentire la comunicazione con il front-end
app.use(express.json());

// Configura il trasportatore Nodemailer (sostituisci con le tue informazioni)
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'sviluppatoreweb@gmail.com',
    pass: '123456',
  },
});

// Definisci la rotta per l'invio delle email
app.post('/invia-email', (req, res) => {
  const { destinatario, oggetto, testo } = req.body;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'sviluppatoreweb@gmail.com',
    to: destinatario,
    subject: oggetto,
    text: testo,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error.toString());
    }
    res.status(200).send('Email inviata con successo: ' + info.response);
  });
});

// Avvia il server sulla porta specificata
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server in ascolto sulla porta ${port}`);
});

component angular import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contatti',
  templateUrl: './contatti.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contatti.component.css']
})
export class ContattiComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  inviaMessaggio(formData: FormData): void {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/send-email', {
      nome: formData.get('name'),
      email: formData.get('email'),
      messaggio: formData.get('message')
    }).subscribe(
      data => {
        // Gestisci la risposta dal server (potrebbe essere un messaggio di conferma, ad esempio)
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Errore durante l\'invio del messaggio:', error);
      }
    );`your text`
  }

  onSubmit(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement);
    this.inviaMessaggio(formData);
  }
}
```